# showSnackBar crash : Null check operator used on a null value. Error thrown null

Tags: flutter

Hello firebase crashlytics report this crash, but I don't understand how to resolve this

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Null check operator used on a null value. Error thrown null.
       at State.context(framework.dart:949)
       at analyse2State.sauvegarde.<fn>.<fn>(tableau_de_bord.dart:2629)
```

in this line :

```
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar
```

---

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: const Text("XXX"),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                      label: 'XXX', onPressed: XXX),
                ));
          });
```

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be in that piece of code. Another way to explain that particular error message: You wrote a `!` somewhere at a variable that was `null`. Since there is no `!` in your code it couldn't have been there

Comment: where did you use this, ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar ? in a page that contain Scaffold?

Comment: You use a delay, the context which is needed for `ScaffoldMessenger` might not be valid after 10 seconds  My guess is that the null check error is thrown by the framework. I recommend checking `mounted` against to true to see if the widget is still 'living'.

Comment: ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar is call only at initState() and on a async function. He is call by my first page of a Pageview, so if I understand, when user switch page before 10s the ScaffoldMessenger return null because of page change ? So I can't stop user to change page as long as the delays continue

Comment: @Nitneuq Yes, if the context that you pass to `ScaffoldMessenger` becomes invalid (when the user navigates away) you can no longer use it safely. In fact it is advised not to use build context between async gaps, and check for `mounted` to ensure the widget is still there.

Comment: You can use a context for messaging that is always valid, for example the context of your top level widget (`MaterialApp`).

Comment: if I use  ->      myfunction()async{ if (this.mounted) { my code } } it will sufficient to prevent null error ?

Comment: I don't know where I need to place mounted, in or before setstate ?  in or before futur.delay ?